# Handling Events for Many Elements - optimalizing my solution

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am building a simple shop website (just to practise) and even though my current solution works, from what I read it is not optimal and could be improved through creating event listener on the parent element (here it would be `cart-items` instead of on every anchor element. The problem is that when I attach event handler to it, then only the first input is changed if there are two or more elements in the basket, no matter which increase button I click (the one from product one, two, ect.).

My question is: in such case is attaching event listener to the parent element really the best option, and if yes, how can I properly refactor my code to make increase/decrease button work on their closest input value, not only on the first one from the rendered list?
Below I attach my current JS Code:

```
const qtyBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-qty-box');

    qtyBoxes.forEach((box) => {
    
        const increase = box.querySelector('.increase');
        const decrease = box.querySelector('.decrease');
        const currQty = box.querySelector('.currQty');
        
        increase.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            currQty.value++;

            $('#przelicz').click(); //uptades UI
        });
        
        decrease.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(currQty.value > 0) { 
               currQty.value--;
            }


            $('#przelicz').click(); //updates UI
        });
        
       
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cart-items">
///... Item 1 code ...

    <div class="qty-box">
       <div class="qty-ctl">
          <a class="incr-btn decrease" data-action="decrease" href="#"></a> 
       </div> 
       <input id="qnt" class="qty currQty input-text" type="text" value="{$poz->count}"/> 
       <div class="qty-ctl"> 
          <a class="incr-btn increase" data-action="increase" href="#"></a> 
       </div>
    </div>
///... Item 2 code ...

    <div class="qty-box">
       <div class="qty-ctl">
          <a class="incr-btn decrease" data-action="decrease" href="#"></a> 
       </div> 
       <input id="qnt" class="qty currQty input-text" type="text" value="{$poz->count}"/> 
       <div class="qty-ctl"> 
          <a class="incr-btn increase" data-action="increase" href="#"></a> 
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I paste a link to the image if the description of what I am trying to build is not clear:
[screenshot of basket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKsOu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is better to attach the event listener to the parent, because you have only one listener instead of multiple listeners (one for every button).

---

You can achieve this by checking to which box the target of the `click`-event (`e.target`) belongs:

```js
const click_parent = e.target.closest('.qty-box');
```

and if it's an increase- or decrease-button, for example:

```js
if (e.target.classList.contains('increase')) {
```

The rest works like in your snippet.

**Working example:**

```js
document.querySelector('.cart-items').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  const click_parent = e.target.closest('.qty-box');
  const currQty = click_parent.querySelector('.currQty');

  if (e.target.classList.contains('increase')) {
    currQty.value++;

    $('#przelicz').click(); //uptades UI
  } else if (e.target.classList.contains('decrease')) {
    if (currQty.value > 0) {
      currQty.value--;
    }

    $('#przelicz').click(); //uptades UI    
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart-items">
  ///... Item 1 code ...

  <div class="qty-box">
    <div class="qty-ctl">
      <a class="incr-btn decrease" data-action="decrease" href="#">decrease</a>
    </div>
    <input id="qnt" class="qty currQty input-text" type="text" value="2" />
    <div class="qty-ctl">
      <a class="incr-btn increase" data-action="increase" href="#">increase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  ///... Item 2 code ...

  <div class="qty-box">
    <div class="qty-ctl">
      <a class="incr-btn decrease" data-action="decrease" href="#">decrease</a>
    </div>
    <input id="qnt" class="qty currQty input-text" type="text" value="3" />
    <div class="qty-ctl">
      <a class="incr-btn increase" data-action="increase" href="#">increase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```